# Function Help - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am unsure of how to modify my function (provided below) to achieve my desired output (displayed at the bottom of the page).

Ideally I would like the function to implement the following:

- The logic I want to implement for First Year Sales = FirstYearSales
- The logic I want to implement for First Full Year Growth = FirstFullYearSales - FirstYearSales
- The logic for the rest of my function (Attrition, Organic Attrition, Organic Growth, None) should only apply to records that dont fall into the first two buckets.

Thoughts?

```
data = [[2015, 900, 2016, 850, 900, 850, 1000, 0, 0, -50, 50, -1000, 0], 
        [2016, 500, 2017, 550, 0, 500, 550, 350, 0, 500, 50, -200, -350], 
        [2017, 200, 2018, 300, 0, 0, 200, 300, 100, 0, 200, 100, -200], 
        [2018, 775, 2019, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 775, 1000, 0, 0, 775, 225], 
        [2019, 30, 2020, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 30]] 
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['cohortYear', 'firstYearSales', 'firstFullYear', 'firstFullYearSales', '2015','2016','2017', '2018', '2019', '2016 Delta', '2017 Delta', '2018 Delta', '2019 Delta'])
data
```

Outputs:

```
                cohortYear  firstYearSales  firstFullYear   firstFullYearSales  2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2016 Delta  2017 Delta  2018 Delta  2019 Delta
            0   2015        900             2016            850                 900     850     1000    0       0      -50          50          -1000       0
            1   2016        500             2017            550                 0       500     550     350     0       500         50          -200        -350
            2   2017        200             2018            300                 0       0       200     300     100     0           200         100         -200
            3   2018        775            2019             1000                0       0       0       775     1000    0           0           775         225
            4   2019        30             2020             0                   0       0       0       0       30      0           0           0           30
```

Function for bucketing:

```
#FUNCTION FOR CATEGORIZING ANNUAL CUSTOMER PURCHASE BEHAVIOR
def bucket(curryear, lastyear):
    if ((lastyear > 0) & (curryear <= 0)):
        return 'Attrition'
    elif ((lastyear > curryear) & (curryear > 0)):
        return 'Organic Attrition'
    elif ((lastyear <= 0) & (curryear > 0)):
        return 'New Sales'
    elif ((curryear > lastyear) & (lastyear > 0)):
        return 'Organic Growth'
    elif ((lastyear == 0) & (curryear == 0)):
        return 'None'
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

Applying function to columns:

```
data['2016 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2016"], x["2015"]), axis=1)
data['2017 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2017"], x["2016"]), axis=1)
data['2018 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2018"], x["2017"]), axis=1)
data['2019 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2019"], x["2018"]), axis=1)
```

Grouping results:

```
cohort2016 = data.groupby(['2016 Bucket'])['2016 Delta'].sum()
cohort2017 = data.groupby(['2017 Bucket'])['2017 Delta'].sum()
cohort2018 = data.groupby(['2018 Bucket'])['2018 Delta'].sum()
cohort2019 = data.groupby(['2019 Bucket'])['2019 Delta'].sum()
```

Dispalying results:

```
cohorts = [cohort2016, cohort2017, cohort2018, cohort2019]
cohorts = pd.DataFrame(cohorts)
cohorts = cohorts.transpose()
cohorts
```

Outputs:

```
                    2016 Delta  2017 Delta  2018 Delta  2019 Delta
New Sales           500.0       200.0       775.0       30.0
None                0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
Organic Attrition   -50.0       NaN         -200.0      -200.0
Organic Growth      NaN         100.0       100.0       225.0
Attrition           NaN         NaN         -1000.0     -350.0
```

Desired Outputs from Function:

```
                        2016 Delta  2017 Delta  2018 Delta  2019 Delta
First Year Sales        500         200         755         30
First Full Year Growth  -50         50          100         225
None                    0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
Organic Attrition       -50.0       NaN         -200.0      -200.0
Organic Growth          NaN         100.0       100.0       225.0
Attrition               NaN         NaN         -1000.0     -350.0
```

Comment: _I am unsure of how to modify my function to achieve my desired output_ Can you be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Just updated to try to make it more clear. Was that helpful?

Comment: To get the `First Year Sales` and `First Full Year Growth` rows, you'll need to update your `bucket` function to have a return value for those. As it stands, each of the conditionals in that function aligns with the rows in the output.

Comment: What values do you expect for the ?

Comment: @David Erickson Will update to reflect the expected values based on the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the final shape of code, but at least I found
the idea for which source value generate *First Year Sales* result:

Change *bucket* function to:

```
def bucket(curryear, lastyear, cohYear,  cohYearValue):
    if cohYear == cohYearValue:
        return 'First Year Sales'
    elif cohYear == cohYearValue - 1:
        return 'First Full Year Growth'
    elif (lastyear > 0) & (curryear <= 0):
        return 'Attrition'
    elif (lastyear > curryear) & (curryear > 0):
        return 'Organic Attrition'
    elif (lastyear <= 0) & (curryear > 0):
        return 'New Sales'
    elif (curryear > lastyear) & (lastyear > 0):
        return 'Organic Growth'
    elif (lastyear == 0) & (curryear == 0):
        return 'None'
    else:
        return 'Other'
```

Then run:

```
data['2016 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2016"], x["2015"], x.cohortYear, 2016), axis=1)
data['2017 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2017"], x["2016"], x.cohortYear, 2017), axis=1)
data['2018 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2018"], x["2017"], x.cohortYear, 2018), axis=1)
data['2019 Bucket'] = data.apply(lambda x: bucket(x["2019"], x["2018"], x.cohortYear, 2019), axis=1)

cohort2016 = data.groupby(['2016 Bucket'])['2016 Delta'].sum()
cohort2017 = data.groupby(['2017 Bucket'])['2017 Delta'].sum()
cohort2018 = data.groupby(['2018 Bucket'])['2018 Delta'].sum()
cohort2019 = data.groupby(['2019 Bucket'])['2019 Delta'].sum()

cohorts = pd.DataFrame([cohort2016, cohort2017, cohort2018, cohort2019]).transpose()\
    .reindex(['First Year Sales', 'First Full Year Growth', 'None',
    'Organic Attrition', 'Organic Growth', 'Attrition'])
cohorts
```

The result I got is:

```
                        2016 Delta  2017 Delta  2018 Delta  2019 Delta
First Year Sales             500.0       200.0       775.0        30.0
First Full Year Growth       -50.0        50.0       100.0       225.0
None                           0.0         0.0         0.0         0.0
Organic Attrition              NaN         NaN      -200.0      -200.0
Organic Growth                 NaN        50.0         NaN         NaN
Attrition                      NaN         NaN     -1000.0      -350.0
```

It is somewhat different from your expected result.
Maybe I didn't understand what is the source for *First Full Year Growth*.
I assumed that from the previous row, compared to *cohYearValue*.

If this is not the case, change the above solution accordingly.

Comment: FirstYearSales is pre-calculated in the column called "FirstYearSales". First Full Year Growth = "FirstFullYearSales" - "FirstYearSales" (both of which are pre-calculated fields in the data frame). The groupby is working as intended. The comparisons of 900 to 850 yield -50 which buckets as 'Organic Attrition'. The comparison of 0 to 500 yields +500 which currently buckets as 'New Sales'. Ideally that +500 should bucket as "FirstYearSales" because it was the first year in which the row purchased. Make sense?

Comment: You got it! Really appreciate it.